# Unexpected change in data-layout happens when applying numpy FFTs

Tags: python, c, numpy, scipy, fft

I was trying to interface Python with C, and at some point I had to pass some `numpy` arrarys after being Fourier transformed. I was in pure despair, literally, for a whole week, facing a bug that was making no sense. In the end, I found out that the bug was introduced by a change in data-layout (strides) of the `numpy` array caused by the `np.fft.fft` operation.

Let me demonstrate it below:

See the following example with 1d FFTs over a 2d `numpy` array.
*This is just a copy-paste of the python interpreter on my Linux PC:*

```
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 19:58:26) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> input = np.zeros((101,50), dtype=np.complex64)
>>> input.real = np.random.uniform(size=(101,50)).astype(np.float32)
>>> input.imag = np.random.uniform(size=(101,50)).astype(np.float32)
>>> input.shape
(101, 50)
>>> input.strides
(400, 8)
>>> output = np.fft.fft(input, axis=0)
>>> output.shape
(101, 50)
>>> output.strides
(16, 1616)
```

Here I basically create a 2d `numpy` array of single-precision complex floats, and then apply FFTs over `axis=0`. Look at the strides of the input and the output array!!! The shapes are the same but the strides differ.

I have no idea what kind of FFT algorithm is this!

Had I used `scipy.fftpack.fft` for this operation, the strides would be as expected:

```
>>> import scipy.fftpack
>>> output = scipy.fftpack.fft(input, axis=0)
>>> output.shape
(101, 50)
>>> output.strides
(400, 8)
```

So, in the `numpy` case, it seems like a virtual FFT operation... where instead of FLOPS, some elements reordering is being performed.

I solved my problem using `scipy`, but I'm curious to learn more. Does anyone have some comments?

Comment: You cannot make assumptions about strides in NumPy arrays. It is likely changing the layout to have the rows being transformed be consecutive in memory?

Comment: The weird thing is that there is a stride of 16, which means it is using a 128-bit complex number, not 64-bit as the input.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Yes you are right, indeed `numpy` implies a change of precision from single to double, Thanks! I don't want to make assumptions, just to point this behavior out and receive some explanations/comments!

Comment: See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17801 for more information about the data type used in `np.fft`.